# Need suggestions for cleaning up mutah questions

Tags: discussion, tag

I'm trying to clean up the questions in [mutah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutah). However, I need your help to clean them.

- **Problem:** We got [1 question asking for shia view](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/570/why-do-shias-allow-mutah-marriage), 2 questions which don't ask for a specific view. However, [One of these 2 questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7566/is-it-halal-to-have-temporary-marriagemutah-in-islam) has only sunni answers and the other [one has both views.](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/833/what-are-temporary-marriages-and-how-are-they-different-from-permanent-ones) lastly, this [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/did-prophet-muhammad-pbuh-ever-observe-temporary-marriage-mutah) is asking if the prophet practiced mutah(Easy to solve, I'll edit my answer to include a link to the cleaned questions fro further reading).
- **Options:**

  1. Change the question that has sunni answers to "sunni view" and close down the other question as too board(or any relevant reason). So in the end we will have 1 question asking for shia view and another question asking for sunni view
  2. Remove the shia view question, the one that has sunni answers, and keep the one that has both answers.

**What do you suggest people?**

For me, the question that has both views doesn't look clean and it is too noisy. So I would go with option 1.